# How do I automatically reset ATI graphics to a known state when users log out of Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, ati

I would like the ATI graphics to default to a known working state when a user logs into Windows XP, regardless of whether that user has tried to change the settings. How do I make that happen?

Comment: Voting to move to SU. Desktop problem, better suited to that community. Unless - if you need to do this for a whole slew of desktops that you manage, for some reason, include that info in an edit to this question.

Answer (score 2):

do you want to lock down the setting or simply reset it? you can reset it with group policy preferences or a login script, or (and what I would likely do) lock the resolution of the system with group policy.  Nowaday unless you are on CRT the resolution should match the resolution of the monitor.